# iOS Deployment Target Missing

Tags: iphone

I'm updating an older iPhone application, and the usual 'Base SDK Missing' pops up.  When I open the project settings and try to set the 'iOS Deployment Target,' it's not in the list.  This is the first time I've encountered this.

I'm able to set the Base SDK to 'Latest SDK' but many of the options are missing from the settings.

What should I do to update this project so it has all the settings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you select "Base SDK for all configurations" in the General tab of the Project Settings to your Latest SDK as if you dont set the base SDK there then by default it will show as " < Multiple Values > ".

Cheers

Comment: Yes, it currently shows as 'Latest iOS (currently set to iOS 4.2).  Still no 'iOS Deployment Target' option under build menu.

Comment: Try selecting "iOS 4.2" and not "Latest OS"

Comment: I changed it, but the option is still not present.

Comment: Ok found it.  Turns out the target wasn't set to latest sdk either.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Change to the latest deployment target in the project settings and then **reload** the project. Failing that restart Xcode but this is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

To fix this error, I had to also change: Build -> Edit Active Target -> Build -> Architecture -> Base SDK

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. but solved it this way:

Select your project in the left hand side, then select the target, and then in **SUMMARY**, select the deployment target.

My problem was that I had not seen this summary page, and it was so simple!