# No provisioned iOS device is connected

Tags: iphone, xcode

I know this question has been asked before - but there are different causes, and the one I'm interested in is as a consequence to updating the test device to iOS4.2.  (I've tried the steps suggested by other threads - they don't help in this case.)

I made the mistake of agreeing to this upgrade on the device - Now my development process is broken.  In XCode, I try to build and run, and I get the error: "No provisioned iOS device is connected"

However - If I drag the apk file into iTunes, I can synch and install to the device that way.

I'm a paid up Apple developer.  I have provisioning profiles that always used to work before.

I have XCode 3.2.4.  I'm reluctant to upgrade.  The download looks like it will take 7 or more hours from the country I'm currently in - plenty of time for a glitch, and a failed download.  (But I will try tonight - I may get lucky).

Can anyone suggest how I can get XCode to test apps on the device WITHOUT the 3.52GB upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to upgrade to xcode 3.2.5 since you have upgraded your iOS to 4.2,XCode won't allow you to build any code in a device of higher version.So go ahead and upgrade your xcode,its not a **BIG** issue,secondly you will also need to upgrade you MAC OS to the latest updates available.

Once you have upgraded everything you can face some issues.You can refer the following  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613100/ios-deployment-target-missing/4613171#4613171) if you face those issues.

Cheers